# How to write "latex-workshop.latex.tools" in VScode settings.json if I'm a tinytex user

Tags: vscode, tinytex

My os is manjaro and I'm quite tired of downloading and installing texlive (5G or even bigger), because I'm familiar with R so I try tinytex instead.

I found the tinytex version "latex-workshop.latex.tools" of xelatex in other user's blog, but for bibtex I cannot get things down.

```
"name": "tinytex_xelatex",
"command": "Rscript",
"args": [
        "-e",
        "tinytex::xelatex(commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)[1],clean=FALSE,engine_args=\"-synctex=1\")",
        "%DOC_EXT%"
        ]
```

Comment: You're saying this works for compiling, but you want another recipe which includes both this tool and bibtex?

Comment: Yeah, but I haven't found it

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late answer. There a two keys in the LaTeX workshop extension which are important: `latex-workshop.latex.recipes` and `latex-workshop.latex.tools`. You said adding `tinytex_xelatex` works for you, so I assume your `latex-workshop.latex.tools` looks like this:

```
"latex-workshop.latex.tools": [
    {
        "name": "tinytex_xelatex",
        "command": "Rscript",
        "args": [
            "-e",
            "tinytex::xelatex(commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)[1],clean=FALSE,engine_args=\"-synctex=1\")",
            "%DOC_EXT%"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "bibtex",
        "command": "bibtex",
        "args": [
            "%DOCFILE%"
        ],
        "env": {}
    },
    (and the defaults)
]
```

Next, a recipe can combine `bibtex` and `tiny_xelatex`. It should look like

```
"latex-workshop.latex.recipes": [
    {
        "name": "tinytex_xelatex",
        "tools": [
            "tinytex_xelatex"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "tinytex+bibtex",
        "tools": [
            "tinytex_xelatex",
            "bibtex",
            "tinytex_xelatex",
            "tinytex_xelatex"
        ]
    },
    (and the defaults)
]
```

Note the first item under `latex-workshop.latex.recipes` is the default compilation. Does this answer your question?

If you have already tried this, could you share any error logs?

Comment: Thank you so much! The bibtex part still doesn't work though....

Comment: What does it say if you execute `bibtex ...` in the command line? (In the directory of your `.tex` file and with `...` replaced by the name of the file without the `.tex` extension)